# How to know about the Balloonist?

Tags: ultima-6

Yes, SinVraal (and all the other Gargoyles) told me that i should reach out for the shrine of Singularity. But sadly it's unreachable, as **you must be able to fly** to enter the shrine.

[image]

### Question:

Who tells me that i have to build a balloon?

### Problem

It's totally obvious that i should try to get the **magic carpet** from Lord British! I have no clue why i should try to get a balloon?! Who gives me the clue to build such an air vessel!? i'm totally stuck.

### Note

*i am aware that i have to ask around in britain for a balloonist, once i have a clue about that* - namely ask Isabella in Minoc or ask Selganor, also located in Minoc. still totally puzzled that i should not use the magic carpet.

Comment: BTW, if my memory serves the carpet isn't even available in the first place in Ultima 6. And IMHO it would have made much more sense since it surely is far easier to carry a carpet around... But for some odd reason it only appears in U5 and later in U7 as a sort of easter egg (this time with bugged seats included)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You already found the one that should give you a clue about asking in Minoc.

This is the full dialogue tree for **Sin'Vraal**

> Temple? "The great Temple of Singularity held the Codex. The Temple is the most holy gargoyle place. A human could learn much by traveling there. But you could never get to the temple. Not only is it deep below the surface, but it can only be reached by flying. And you cannot fly any more than I can."
> Fly? "There are two kinds of gargoyles: winged ones and wingless ones. Wingless ones are mute and unintelligent. They do all the manual labor. Winged ones are smart, and do all the planning and leading. Being able to fly is, to them, a sign of intelligence. Even the Temple can only be reached by air."
> Intelligence? "Yes, a strange concept this. Yet as some in Minoc can tell you, flying can be achieved by anyone."

Notice that there is a second trail that you could follow, but that would require you to listen by chance to a specific song from an NPC in Buccaneer's Den.

[image]

He mentions a balloon in one of his songs and will direct you to a book if you ask him about that. In the end the book will still point you to Minoc.

So, right now, your most natural option is to just ask the Gargoyle about what he meant by "intelligent" .

Comment: i can only bath in your radiance - you seem to know anything, i stumble across all obstacles! thanks again! i was able to follow your instructions in every answer you gave - and i am glad you are there!

Comment: @MartinFrank I suppose that it may have something to do with the fact that I actually helped as a Seer on a custom UO server for quite a while....